# httpcontext current server mappath shows c:\inetpub\wwwroot when the current location is somewhere else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis, mappath

I have taken on a MVC project, in VS 2008, from another developer and I need to know why `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/")` is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

I am running the project from `c:\Websites\Customer\Web\Website\Application\`

IIS shows that the site is running from: `c:\Websites\Customer\Web\Website\Application\` so I am ultra confused.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Server.MapPath("~")`, which returns the physical path of the root of your **application**.

The `Server.MapPath("/")` you are using, returns the physical path of the root of the **domain**.